# Almost sure limit of $\log(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n) - \log(n)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_n$ be an i.i.d. sequence of positive random variables with expectation 2 and variance 1.

What is the almost sure limit of
$$\log(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n) - \log(n)$$ 
as $n \to \infty$

Would it be just $$\log \left( \frac{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n}{n} \right)$$ which by strong law of large numbers is  then $$\log(\mu) = \log(2)$$

Comment: Yes, provided you replace "which by strong law of large numbers is then" by "which, by the strong law of large numbers, converges almost surely to".